# NSTableView: Resizable last column

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

NSTableView: Resizable last column

The last column in my `NSTableView` is not resizable by the user, even after it's dragged leftwards, so it's not the last column anymore. 
I've already disabled *auto*resizing on the `NSTableView` and on all the `NSTableColumns`, but it did not help:

```
nsTableViewInstance.ColumnAutoresizingStyle = NSTableViewColumnAutoresizingStyle.None;
nsTableColumnViewInstance.ResizingMask = NSTableColumnResizing.UserResizingMask; // in ctor, for all
```

Is there a way to make all the columns resizable?

Comment: If you want all of the columns to be resizable, why are you disabling resizing on the tableview and all columns?  Is there an extra or missing "not" in this question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant _auto_ resizing is disabled. (fixed the question now)

Comment: Is the tableview configured in a nib? What are the values of Resizing, Column Sizing of the tableview and Resizing of the column? What are the minimum and maximum width of the column?

Comment: The TableView is fully configured from code, I use no nibs at all. To answer the other questions:
tableView.AllowsColumnResizing = true;
tableView.ColumnAutoresizingStyle = NSTableViewColumnAutoresizingStyle.None;
tableColumn.ResizingMask = NSTableColumnResizing.UserResizingMask;
tableColumn.MinWidth and MaxWidth are not set by me, so their default values are 10 and 3.4E+38

Comment: It turned out there was a bug in my code, so the above is not true. See my answer, and sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there was a bug in my code, and this
`nsTableColumnViewInstance.ResizingMask = NSTableColumnResizing.UserResizingMask;`
got later overridden to `NSTableColumnResizing.Autoresizing` for the last column. Removing it solved the problem.

So the construction shown in the question works properly, all columns are resizable.